# Oracle: How to use left outer join to get all entries from left table and satisfying the condition in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have the tables below.

Client:

```
ID | clientName
--------------
1    A1        
2    A2
3    A3
```

Order:

```
OrdID clientID status_cd
------------------------
100  1        DONE
101  1        SENT
102  3       SENT
```

Status:

```
status_cd  status_category
DONE        COMPL
SENT        INPROG
```

I have to write a query to get all the clients and count of order against all of them, whether the client_id exists in Order table or not and has the orders with "COMPL" as status category.

In this case, I am using the query below but it's filtering out the clients which has no orders. I want to get all clients such that the expected result is as below.

Query:

```
select c.ID, count(distinct o.OrdID) 
from client c, order o, status s
where c.ID=o.client_id(+)
and o.status_cd=s.status_cd where s.status_category='COMPL'
group by c.ID
```

Expected result:

```
C.ID   count(distinct o.OrdID)
---------------------------- 
1       1
2       0
3       0
```

Can someone please help me with this? I know, in this case, left outer join is behaving like inner join when I am using where clause, but is there any other way to achieve the results above?

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the `(+)` for outer joins. Use an explicit `left join` instead.

Comment: Read the oracle documentation for "(+)" notation. You are not using it properly to get an outer join. (It is ignored.) Even oracle says don't even use it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be dealt with a lot easier when using an explicit join operator:

```
select c.ID, count(distinct s.status_cd) 
from client c
  left join orders o on o.clientid = c.id
  left join status s on s.status_cd = o.status_cd and s.status_category='COMPL'
group by c.ID;
```

The above assumes that `orders.status_cd` is defined as `not null`

Another option is to move the join between orders and status in a derived table:

```
select c.ID, count(distinct o.ordid) 
from client c
  left join (
    select o.ordid
    from orders o
      join status s on s.status_cd = o.status_cd
    where s.status_category='COMPL'
  ) o on o.clientid = c.id
group by c.ID;
```

The above "states" more clearly (at least in my eyes) that only orders within that status category are of interest compared to the first solution

Answer (score 0):

As usual, there are lots of ways to express this requirement.

Try ANSI join people will hate me an vote down  this answer ;) :

```
select c.ID, count(distinct o.OrdID) 
from client c, order o, status s
where c.ID = o.client_id(+)
and o.status_cd = s.status_cd 
and s.status_category='COMPL'
group by c.ID
;
```

or

```
select c.ID
, nvl((select count(distinct o.OrdID) 
   from order o, status s 
   where c.ID = o.client_id 
     and o.status_cd = s.status_cd 
     and s.status_category='COMPL'
   ), 0) as order_count
from client c
group by c.ID
;
```

or

```
with ord as
(select client_id, count(distinct o.OrdID) cnt
   from order o, status s 
   where 1=1
     and o.status_cd = s.status_cd 
     and s.status_category='COMPL'
   group by client_id
)
select c.ID
, nvl((select cnt from ord o where c.ID = o.client_id ), 0) as order_count
from client c
group by c.ID
;
```

or

...

Comment: If you get downvotes, they will not necessarily be for using Oracle notation. For example: in your first solution, you will not get the correct result, because you are still not LEFT joining to the third table (regardless of notation/syntax).

Comment: Hello @mathguy.  I've seen some of your comments and answers and find them to be high caliber.  It's interesting that you have a SQL compiler and execution engine built in; I just  have a SQL compiler built into my brain.  I'm not actually worried about down votes, I really just find them curious.  I've been using Oracle since 1985 (v4) and still do make mistakes as I'm sure most do.  Anyway, you don't get to be my age in this field if you have too thin a skin.

Comment: Thanks a ton Roger. I tried the below approach and it did work : select c.ID
, nvl((select count(distinct o.OrdID) 
   from order o, status s 
   where c.ID = o.client_id 
     and o.status_cd = s.status_cd 
     and s.status_category='COMPL'
   ), 0) as order_count
from client c
group by c.ID
;

Answer (score 0):

The second WHERE should be an AND.

Other than that, you need the plus sign, `(+)`, marking left outer join, in the second join condition as well. It is not enough to left-outer-join the first two tables.

Something like

```
select c.ID, count(distinct o.OrdID) 
from client c, order o, status s
where c.ID=o.client_id(+)
and o.status_cd=s.status_cd(+)    AND   s.status_category='COMPL'
--                         ^^^    ^^^  (not WHERE)
group by c.ID
```

Of course, it would be much better if you used proper (SQL Standard) join syntax.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo the second where was AND only and it was not bringing back the expected results.

Comment: @user5252179 - you still have the issue of missing the `(+)` in the second join condition. Did **that** answer your question?